# stop execution in Custom validator if it false

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two textboxes as to_date and from_date.  and i compare both textboxes and get value but it execution goes next to onclick of button that i want to stop because if to_date is less than from date, the to date is become null as well as focus on that textboxes not goes to click event of button.

i use :

```
 try
        {
            DateTime from = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_from_date.Text, "M/d/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
            DateTime to = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_to_date.Text, "M/d/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(to, from);
            e.IsValid = result>0;
            if (e.IsValid == false)
            {
                txt_to_date.Text = "";
                txt_to_date.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eq)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            txt_to_date.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: why you dont handle this in your webpage...you can restrict user to input to_date greater than from_date using jquery.

Comment: what is the code of your onclick event handler? Did you put `Page.Validate();if(Page.IsValid) { // your code }` ?

Answer (score 2):

If your onclick event handler, you have to call the validation :

```
protected void YourButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if(Page.IsValid) // Will be false if any validator is invalid
    {
         // your code here
    }
}
```

Note that you can set the `ValidationGroup` on validation controls and pass the same value to `Page.Validate` method, if you have to split your form in several sub sections.